# Why is Outlook 2003 showing full headers in the message body area?

Tags: email, yahoo-mail, microsoft-outlook

I am having a strange problem with Outlook 2003.

It seems that random emails are not being parsed properly and Outlook shows a blank sender and blank subject, and then the full headers in the message body when it is opened. This only happens for some messages - some display as expected.

We're running Outlook 2003 on Windows XP and POP3 download from Yahoo Mail - although they display perfectly well in Yahoo before they are downloaded.

Which settings should we be looking at to try to fix this? I can provide screenshots on request.

Comment: Is there any consistency as to the source? If they all come from the same site/server/service then that would help identify the cause.

Comment: @Andrew Lott Not sure - looking just now, seems like a lot of "marketing" emails get through but looks like it's because they're HTML - all the plaintext ones from "people" are being displayed full headers - thought it was a Yahoo bug where they weren't formatting it properly, but sent myself a couple of tests as plaintext and they came through - so very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a problem with AVG anti-virus mailscanner

We disabled the mailscanner and the problem disappeared.

We then updated AVG to the latest version (2013) and then re-enabled it, and the problem didn't occur again.

Not sure whether it was the upgrade or the "reset" which solved the problem, but would advise trying that if the question describes your problem.